# Access the method inside the addMouseListener() method

Tags: java, class, methods

I want to return the count of mouse clicks every time the panel is clicked. I have a BasePanel class that has this code snippet:

```
    BasePanel(){ //inside the BasePanel Class
        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e){
                if(clicked == troop1){
                    count1--;
                    count = count1; //i want count to be accessible in another class
                    System.out.println("Troop1 count: "+count);
                }else if(clicked == troop2){
                    count2--;
                    count = count2;
                    System.out.println("Troop2 count: "+count);
                }
            }
            public int getCount(){ //how can this method be accessible in another class
                return count;
            }
        });
    }
```

Here, I wanted to return the count variable. I want the ButtonsPanel class  to be able to access the getCount() method in BasePanel class.

```
    ButtonsPanel(){ //inside the ButtonsPanel class
        BasePanel pane = new BasePanel();
        troop1 = new JButton(""+pane.getCount());
        troop2 = new JButton(""+pane.getCount());
    }
```

But I think, the way I access the getCount() method in the ButtonsPanel class is wrong.

Comment: What kind of class is `BasePanel`? `JButton` has `.getMouseListeners()` (see [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#getMouseListeners--))

Comment: BasePanel extends JPanel and has a mouseListener method that everytime the mouse clicks it, the count variable decreases by 1. I want the count variable be printed in the button in ButtonsPanel class.

Comment: `JPanel` also has `.getMouseListeners()` ([documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#getMouseListeners())) so if you only have one event listener you can just use `pane.getMouseListeners()[0].getCount()` to call the method.

Comment: I still receive an error that getCount() method cannot be found.

Answer (score 1):

`getCount()` is a method of the anonymous class implementation of `MouseAdapter`.

If you want to be able to access it, you'll have to pull it out of anonymity:

```
BasePanel(){
    MouseAdapter mouseAdapter = new MouseAdapter(){
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e){
            if(clicked == troop1){
                count1--;
                count = count1; //i want count to be accessible in another class
                System.out.println("Troop1 count: "+count);
            }else if(clicked == troop2){
                count2--;
                count = count2;
                System.out.println("Troop2 count: "+count);
            }
        }
        public int getCount(){
            return count;
        }
    });

    addMouseListener(mouseAdapater);
}
```

And add a getter method to your class:

```
public MouseAdapter getMouseAdapater() {
    return mouseAdapter;
}
```

And then you can access it as such:

```
ButtonsPanel(){ //inside the ButtonsPanel class
    BasePanel pane = new BasePanel();
    MouseAdapter adapater = pane.getMouseAdapater();
    troop1 = new JButton(""+adapater.getCount());
    troop2 = new JButton(""+adapater.getCount());
}
```

Comment: I don't know how to use MouseAdapter. Is that the right syntax for using the method? I'm receiving an "error: ';' expected });"

Comment: @Syche That means you're missing a ; somewhere. Remember that in Java all statements require a semicolon at the end of the line.

Comment: There is also an error in the method getMouseAdapater() that says: illegal start of expression  public MouseAdapter getMouseAdapater() {
           ^

Comment: Yes, it's because the code you provided seems to be for a method rather than a class as you've declared. I'll edit my answer to be more specific in that you need to put the `getMouseAdapater` inside a class (I'm assuming the code you provided is for a method, not a class, because you have the `addMouseAdapter` instruction inside it).

Comment: Yes, the BasePanel class just looks like this: 

    class BasePanel extends JPanel{BasePanel(){}}